# The "src" option from the configuration file will be ignored

Tags: testcafe

I am currently creating my own js configuration files.

Here is an example of my .js comfig file
( I've removed some sensitive data due to security )

```js
module.exports = {
    disableHttp2: true,
    reporter: 'spec-time',
    disableMultipleWindows: true,
    proxy: 'PROXY',
    clientScripts: 'SCRIPTSPATH',
    src: ['./Tests/Desktop/**/*.js'],
    filter: {
        testMeta: {
            type: 'regression',
            priority: 'high' || 'low',
        },
    },
};
```

I also tried same configuration but with JSON format

```json
{
    "disableHttp2": true,
    "reporter": "spec-time",
    "disableMultipleWindows": true,
    "proxy": "PROXY",
    "clientScripts": "SCRIPTSPATH",
    "src": "./Tests/Desktop/**/*.js",
    "filter": {
        "testMeta": {
            "type": "regression",
            "priority": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run those config files through CLI with a command from root folder like this:

```
testcafe firefox --skip-js-errors --env staging --debug-on-fail --config-file customConfig.js
```

TestCafe gives me a message in console
"The "src" option from the configuration file will be ignored."

I was wondering why exactly TestCafe ignores specified SRC path and how can I overcome this behaviour?

TestCafe version 2.4.0

I am sure that the src path I am using is 100% correct since currently I'm using the same path to specify it in the CLI command and it works correctly, taking only the tests from the path I've provided + applying the configuration file filtering and set ups.

I also tried to specify the src as both

```
"src": "./Tests/Desktop/**/*.js",` and `"src": "/Tests/Desktop/**/*.js",
```

same outcome

```
testcafe firefox ./Tests/Desktop/**/*.js --skip-js-errors --env staging --debug-on-fail --config-file customConfig.js
```

I tried to use default testcaferc.json file instead of creating a custom one but src is also ignored in this case.

Note that providing path in cli works as expected but it doesn't suite my needs since I'm trying to remove this cli dependency and move it to configuration files.

In the TestCafe documentation I didn't find anything about this error or why src is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce the issue. It happens because you send `--env staging` to CLI. `--env` is an unknown option for `TestCafe`, which is why TestDafe doesn't handle it correctly. Please [create a new issue in the TestCafe repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml) with the problem.
Now, you have two ways:

1. Send the path to tests in CLI.
2. Use another way to send environment variables to your process - for example, via `process.env`.